# Access user's news feeds via Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Pacific controls systems is developing a web application which includes gadget. we have a requirement to show a user's news feeds in a gadget. This requirement could be fulfilled with "me/home" Facebook API endpoint but this endpoint is deprecated right now.

Facebook API documentation redirect developers to use "me/feed" instead "me/home". To get access to user's news feeds we need "read_stream" permission. But according to Facebook support forum, this permission only be granted to apps which aims on platforms where Facebook is not already available.

Is there any workaround available to fulfill our requirement?.

Answer (score 0):

`read_stream` does not exist anymore since a very long time. You can use `user_posts` instead, just keep in mind that you will not get all posts. Detailed information can be found in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3

Possible feed endpoints are listed in the API reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/feed

Usage of `user_posts` has to get reviewed by Facebook before it can be used for users without a role in the App, it is called "Login Review": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review